# Update two html files at the same time using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am very new to this topic so it might be a simple question but I could not answer it by googling.

I have two HTML files and a javascript file (see below). The first HTML file contains an input field where an user can enter a temperature in degree celcius. This number is then converted to the temperature in Kelvin using a javascript function called "convTemp".

Problem is the output. I would like to get the result printed on both HTML pages (in "< p id="output" > text to be replaced < /p >") but currently it works only for one of the files. How can I modify the javascript file/HTML files to update both HTML files at the same time and not only one? Any comments are welcome! If it is not possible using javascript, how else could it be done?

Here are the files I use demonstrating the problem using a small toy example:

HTML file number 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript-Test</title>
<script src="JSfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Calc">
<input type="text" name="myNumber" size="3">
<input type="button" value="convert temperatures" onclick="convTemp(document.Calc.myNumber.value, 'output')"><BR>
<p id="output">Here the output will appear and a new tab will open as well.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML file number 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML number 2</title>
<script src="JSfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output">This replacement does not work yet</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
 function convTemp(x, tID) {
     var res = parseFloat(x) + 273.15;
     window.open('htmlfile2.html'); /*, "_self" */
     document.getElementById(tID).innerHTML = x + " degrees are " + res + " Kelvin.";
}
```

Edit:
I tried the localStorage solution but it still does not work. The js file now looks as follows:

```
function convTemp(x) {

   var res = parseFloat(x) + 273.15;
   /*window.open('htmlfile2.html'); /*, "_self" */


   if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("resCalc", res);
        window.location.href = 'htmlfile2.html';
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x + " degrees are  "     + localStorage.getItem("resCalc") + " Kelvin.";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }   
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit 2: I added a working solution (see below). If anyone has a better solution, please post it - thanks!

Comment: you need some back end for this. javascript can sent ajax on server from first page, and server can sent signal to update second page

Comment: OK, and how would I do this? Could you provide some keywords or anything? Thanks!
(and why is this question downvoted 10 seconds after it appeared?)

Comment: which technology you are using on back-end?

Comment: @epascarello: the files are currently just in the same folder. That's it. When the number is entered, the javascript function is called and opens the second page using "window.open". There is no other connection at the moment but seems it needs something else.

Comment: @kpblc: currently, the files are just located in the same folder but I can also upload them to a server.

Answer (score 2):

By using localStorage - as suggested by epascarello and Michael - I could solve the problem although I doubt that it is the most aesthetic one.

Here are the files, maybe someone else runs into this problem or can suggest a better solution later on:

htmlFile1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript-Test</title>
<script src="JSfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="Calc">
     <input type="text" name="myNumber" size="3">
     <input type="button" value="convert temperatures"    onclick="convTemp(document.Calc.myNumber.value)"><BR>
  <div id="output">Here the output will appear and a new tab will open as well.</div>
</html>
```

htmlfile.2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML number 2</title>
<script src="JSfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">This replacement does work now.</div>
    <script>showData();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js file JSfunc.js:

```
function convTemp(x) {

   var res = parseFloat(x) + 273.15;

   if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        //localStorage.setItem("resCalc", resString);
        setData("resCalc", res.toString());
        setData("origVal", x);
        showData();
        window.open('htmlfile2.html'); //, "_self" 
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }

}

function setData(tfield, tval)
{
    localStorage.setItem(tfield, tval);
}

function showData()
{
    var tstr = localStorage.getItem("resCalc");
    var x = localStorage.getItem("origVal");

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x + " degrees are " + tstr + " Kelvin.";  
}
```

Comments/improvements are always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to do this. You can send a message to other window so that you can update both.

Maybe:

```
var otherwindow = window.open("htmlfile2.html");
otherwindow.postMessage({ x: x, res: res }, "*");
```

And in HTML file number 2:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (ev) {
  // Update your HTML using ev.data
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will read about it. Do you know how to apply it for my case?

Comment: @Cleb I added a short example. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can only alter the current DOM with javascript, but you can use e.g. cookies to get the data displayed on both pages after changing those on one page. Preferably, if you use **php or any server side language** too, the way to go would be to save the entries in your database and pull them from there.

here's a function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) to create and retrieve cookies.

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

**USAGE:**

Set the cookie:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript-Test</title>
<script src="JSfunc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Calc">
<input type="text" name="myNumber" id="myNumber" size="3">
<input type="button" value="convert temperatures" onclick="convTemp(document.Calc.myNumber.value, 'output')"><BR>
<p id="output">Here the output will appear and a new tab will open as well.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFunc.js:

```
document.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('myNumber').addEventListener('keyup', addtoCookie);
function addtoCookie() {
var inputs = document.getElementById('myNumber').value

var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
createCookie('entry',inputs,30);
}
}
```

You can then load the content from the cookie on page load:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript-Test Page2</title>
<script src="JSfunc2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="output">Here the output will appear and a new tab will open as well.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFunc2.js (let's say the cookie is called 'entry'):

```
document.onload=function() {
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getCookie('entry');

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this long answer. I will try it.

Comment: Using cookies is not the best idea. Localstorage would be better.

Comment: Yes that's true, I thought about localstorage too when I wrote the answer. @epascarello

Comment: how would the local storage solution look like? Thanks!
@all: Although I have not tried all the solutions yet, I'll upvote all of them, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @epascarello and michael
 
I now tried this localStorage solution but it still does not work; only the first page is updated. The edited code can be found above. Would be nice if you helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Send it in the querystring

```
window.open('htmlfile2.html?temp=' + encodeURIComponent(res));
```

read it on the next page

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var temp = getParameterByName('temp');
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Ok, I will check this solution as well, thanks for that!